# how to convert a 3x3 matrix to an RGB image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

suppose that I have the following code:

```
clc
clear
band1 = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\DrAkhundzadeh\Bands\band1.tif');
band2 = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\DrAkhundzadeh\Bands\band2.tif');
band3 = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\DrAkhundzadeh\Bands\band3.tif');
band4 = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\DrAkhundzadeh\Bands\band4.tif');
band5 = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\DrAkhundzadeh\Bands\band5.tif');
band7 = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\DrAkhundzadeh\Bands\band7.tif');
Vegetation = band4-band3;
Oxide = band3-band1;
Hydroxyl = band5-band7;
%Normalize
NormalizedVegetation = ( Vegetation - min(min(Vegetation)))*255/(max(max(Vegetation)) - min(min(Vegetation)));
NormalizedOxide = ( Oxide - min(min(Oxide)))*255/(max(max(Oxide)) - min(min(Oxide)));
NormalizedHydroxyl = ( Hydroxyl - min(min(Hydroxyl)))*255/(max(max(Hydroxyl)) - min(min(Hydroxyl)));
FalseColor(:,:,1) = NormalizedVegetation;
FalseColor(:,:,2) = NormalizedOxide;
FalseColor(:,:,3) = NormalizedHydroxyl;
RGBIMAG = uint8(FalseColor);
imshow(RGBIMAG);
```

my problem is with the line:

```
RGBIMAG = uint8(FalseColor);
```

which causes all the image to get darked. How can I tell matlab that each level of the 3 dimensional matrix are different band of an RGB image without changing its elements.

Comment: Tip: `min(x(:))` is nicer to read (and write) than `min(min(x))`

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, it should work and I tried something similar on my machine. There's nothing you should tell Matlab, just make sure your values make sense. @Notlikethat is right, min(x(:)) is much better, but I would simply use mat2gray, it's even simpler.

Comment: well @Vadim it does not work properly. every thing gets dark when I use both normalization section and uint8

Comment: What data type are the original images loaded as? If it's integer you could be getting saturation/truncation in the normalisation step, which would mess things up. How does `band1 = double(imread(...` etc. affect things?

Answer (score 0):

For converting to uint8, you must use:

```
RGBIMAG = im2uint8(FalseColor);
```

That function receives ur double array( values btw 0-1 ) and converts them to RGB values in the range (0, 255).